# Unable to load library 'gsdll32'

Tags: java, ghostscript

I am running following code to create bmp image from pdf using Ghost4j

i have a commad which is executed by GhostScript generator to generate Bmp image of a page from pdf.
Code is:

```
package ghost;

import net.sf.ghost4j.Ghostscript;
import net.sf.ghost4j.GhostscriptException;

public class GhostDemo {
public static void main(String[] a){
    Ghostscript gs = Ghostscript.getInstance(); //create gs instance
    String[] gsArgs = new String[10];/*command string array*/
    gsArgs[0] = "-dUseCropBox";/*use crop box*/
    gsArgs[1] = "-dNOPAUSE";
    gsArgs[2] = "-dBATCH";
    gsArgs[3] = "-dSAFER";
    gsArgs[3] = "-r300";
    gsArgs[4] = "-sDEVICE=bmp16m";
    gsArgs[6] = "-dTextAlphaBits=4";
    gsArgs[5] = "-sOutputFile=C:/PagesWorkspace/1/masterData/1.bmp";/*bmp file location with name*/
    gsArgs[6] = "C:/MasterWorkspace/pipeline.pdf";/*pdf location with name*/

    try {

        gs.initialize(gsArgs);  /*initialise ghost interpreter*/
        gs.exit();

    } catch (GhostscriptException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

i am getting Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gsdll32': The specified module could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:145)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:188)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:123)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:255)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:241)
    at net.sf.ghost4j.GhostscriptLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(GhostscriptLibraryLoader.java:36)
    at net.sf.ghost4j.GhostscriptLibrary.<clinit>(GhostscriptLibrary.java:32)
    at net.sf.ghost4j.Ghostscript.initialize(Ghostscript.java:292)
    at ghost.GhostDemo.main(GhostDemo.java:22)
```

Can any one tell me why i am getting this exception?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you have Ghostscript installed at all?

- If yes, which version?
- If yes, in which location?
- Does it include a file `gsdll32.dll`?

If not, [**download the Ghostscript installer for Win32**](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/gs905w32.exe) and run it. After the installation, there should be a file `gsdll32.dll` in directory `%your_install_dir%\gs\gs9.05\bin\`

Comment: working fine after I copied this dll to Windows/system32 folder

Comment: where can someone find the `.dll` for 64-bit?

Answer (score 6):

Pasting dll file in eclipse project made my program work!

Answer (score 2):

For the SO community, another thing to check with this error is that you are using 32-bit Java.  If your instance of Java is 64-bit, you will get the exact same message:

`Unable to load library 'gsdll32': The specified module could not be found.`

without any further explanation even if you *are* pointing to the correct dll.